# L'adverbe "si" au Québec

Tags: étymologie, québec

Voici quelques exemples d'utilisations du mot "si" comme adverbe signifiant "au contraire" ou "n'est-ce-pas" :

- Vous n’allez pas voir ce spectacle ? — Si, nous y allons.
- Ce spectacle n’est pas agréable. — Si ! (sous-entendu « oui, il l’est »).
- Elle n’est pas méchante, si ?

Le mot "si" est très rarement utilisé en français québécois alors qu'il est couramment utilisé en France. S'agit-il d'une utilisation relativement récente du mot "si" ?

Je m'interroge sur les raisons pour lesquelles "si" n'est que très peu utilisé pour dire "au contraire" ou "n'est-ce-pas" au Québec. N'hésitez pas me faire part de vos hypothèses.

Comment: C'est le contraire, le ''si'' est très ancien en français, et c'est une nouveauté relativement récente qu'il le perde en français du Québec, en s'anglicisant.

Answer (score 9):

Il ne s'agit pas d'une utilisation récente, *si* existait déjà au moyen-âge.

*Si* vient du latin *sic* (ainsi) alors que *oui* vient de *hoc ille* ou *hoc il* (celui-ci). Le premier a évolué pour indiquer *oui* dans la plupart des langues romanes sauf le français et quelques langues aujourd'hui régionales où c'est le second qui s'en est chargé.

Quand il s'applique à une proposition affirmative, *oui* signifie à la fois la confirmation de cette affirmation et l'accord sur sa véracité (c'est vrai). De même, *non* infirme l'affirmation et aussi sa fausseté (c'est faux).

- Tu viens ? - Oui ! (je viens)
- Tu viens ? - Non ! (je ne viens pas)

Quand il s'applique à une proposition négative, *non* confirme en la reprenant la négation mais *oui* est ambigu en français de France car il risque d'être compris comme un acquiescement (c'est vrai). *Si* permet de lever cette ambiguïté et indique clairement que l'on infirme ce qui vient d'être dit.

- Tu ne viens pas ? - Non ! (Je ne viens pas)
- Tu ne viens pas ? - Oui ! (?? - Oui, je ne viens pas)
- Tu ne viens pas ? - Si ! (Je viens)

En résumé, que l'on réponde *oui* ou *non* à une question négative, cette réponse signifie toujours « je suis d'accord ». Au contraire, *si* permet de marquer son désaccord.

S'il faut trouver une influence étrangère, je doute fort qu'il y a un rapport avec d'autres langues romanes comme l'italien ou l'espagnol car ces dernières, comme l'anglais ou le français québécois ne distinguent pas le *oui* affirmatif du *oui* infirmatif (désaccord) (voir [cette réponse](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/9940/2268) pour l'espagnol). Je pencherait pour celle des Francs (germaniques) qui distinguaient très probablement déjà ces deux *oui* comme le fait l'allemand moderne qui utilise *ja* pour *oui* et *doch* pour *si* (c.f. anglais *though*).

Le *si* étant probablement suffisamment établi en français lors de l'arrivée des colons en Amérique du nord, une disparition de celui-ci due à l'influence de l'anglais est plausible.

Answer (score 3):

Je suis pas professeur de français, mais je voudrais deviner une réponse.

La France se trouve près des autres pays latins. Les Italiens et les Espagnols disent **si** pour dire oui. Je crois que c'est une affaire culturelle. On a notre langage à nous au Québec. Le français n'est pas pareil partout et c'est de même avec les autres langages du monde.

Comment: Le ''si'' en français existe bien parce que c'est une langue latine, mais n'a rien à voir avec un emprunt à l'espagnol ou à l'italien. Le Québécois, à la base avait aussi le ''si'' français, mais sous l'influence de l'anglais, il le perd de plus en plus.