# Pourquoi répondre si

Tags: questions

Responding to an affirmative question:

> — Tu vas à la piscine ?  — Oui, j'aime la natation. (Agreeing — you
>   will go)
>
> — Tu vas à la piscine ?  — Non, je déteste la natation. (Disagreeing
>   — you will not go)
>
> Responding to a negative question
>
> — Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?  — No, je déteste la natation.
>   (Agreeing — you will not go)
>
> — Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?  — Si, j'aime la natation.
>   (Disagreeing — you will go)

Statement:

> (...)Certes. Ça ne nous dit pas la qualité du traducteur, ou plutôt, peut-être bien que si.

Why one has to respond using 'si' instead of 'oui' to disagree with a negative question or statement ? From where comes this particular use of 'si' in French ? (I know that 'si' means yes in several languages.)

Comment: Although [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25102/why-does-si-sometimes-mean-if-and-other-times-so/25106#25106) deals with a different sense of *si*, it might shed some light on how this development happened. *Si* is from a Latin word meaning "thus, so, in that way". You can imagine a generalized question and answer: "Is it not so? (Tu ne vas pas ?)" — "It *is* so. (Je vais.)"

Comment: See also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16903/ladverbe-si-au-qu%C3%A9bec/16905#16905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu réponds *si* pour la simple raison que si tu répondais *oui*, il y aurait ambiguïté.

De fait, avec ton *tu ne vas pas à la piscine ?* La réponse *oui* isolée, pourrait signifier que celui qui est ainsi interrogé acquiesce.

Il semble que l'ambigüité sur les réponses aux questions négatives soit si crainte qu'il est fréquent, dans la réponse d'entendre ajouté le verbe de la question, en reprenant ton exemple :

*Tu ne vas pas à la piscine ? - Si, j'y vais*